# How to create two dimensional array when I have an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
 const object = {name: ['Jim', 'Jack', 'Betty'],
                 age: [14, 15, 16],
                 gender: ['M', 'M', 'F']}
```

What I want is to create a text like that:

```
Jim   14   M
Jack  15   M
Betty 16   F
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `map()`

```js
const object = {
  name: ['Jim', 'Jack', 'Betty'],
  age: [14, 15, 16],
  gender: ['M', 'M', 'F']
}

const transpose = (arr) => arr[0].map((_, colIndex) => arr.map(row => row[colIndex]));

const transposed = transpose([object.name, object.age, object.gender])

const result = transposed.map(row => row.join('\t')).join('\n')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific properties and have same length, this does the trick:

```js
 const object = {name: ['Jim', 'Jack', 'Betty'],
                 age: [14, 15, 16],
                 gender: ['M', 'M', 'F']}
const [names,ages,genders] = Object.values(object);
const rows = names.map((name, i)=>[name, ages[i], genders[i]]);
const result = rows.map(row => row.join('\t')).join('\n')

console.log(result)
```